lattice RLWE encryption and decryption process
I am here trying to solve an issue that I face a lot during solving RLWE.
The issue is that I am not able to retrieve the original message after the decryption process.
I use the following encryption equation:
$c_1(x)=A(x)\cdot  r(x)+e_1(x) \bmod  R$
$c_2(x)=B(x)\cdot  r(x)+e_2(x)+\lfloor q/2 \rfloor \cdot m(x) \bmod  R$
and this decryption equation:
$m′(x)=c_2​(x)−s(x)\cdot c_1​(x) \bmod R$
first of all, I am not very familiar with rounding, maybe that's why I get the wrong answer every time. I used to divide the coefficients by (floor(q/2)) and round to the nearest integer!
the retrieved message I get is way far from the original message :(
Could you please explain the correct rounding technique?

What is $s(x)$?

@kelalaka it is the secret polynomial

What do you expect in the result?

@kelalaka the result should be a polynomial that contains the sent message with some noise in it.

some noise? How do you plan to remove the noise?

@kelalaka here is where I am stuck. the standard procedure is to use the rounding technique to remove the noise and extract the message. However, it is not working for me for some reason!

The error is in your rounding function. I'm assuming that the message polynomial $m(x)$ has coefficients either 0 or 1.
To decrypt, you need to compute $m'(x) = c_2(x) - s(x) \cdot c_1(x) \bmod R$ which is equal to $m'(x) = \lfloor q/2 \rfloor \cdot m(x) + ( e_2(x) - s(x) \cdot e_1(x)) \bmod R$. After this, you need to look at each coefficient of $m'(x)$ and set it to 0 if the coefficient is close to $0$ or $q$. Otherwise, set it to 1 if the coefficient is close to $\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$. This works because $e_2(x) - s(x) \cdot e_1(x)$ is a polynomial with small coefficients.

Thank you very much. I will try that and let you know.

could you please verify that I am using the correct encryption and decryption equations?
I think there is a problem with the encryption process!
Is it okay for the secret (S) to have negative values?
During the encryption, the polynomials (r, e1, e2) are sampled from the discrete gaussian distribution, correct?
Thank you in advance

is this a correct encryption equation: c2(x)=B(x)⋅r(x)+e2(x)+m(x)mod  R ?

You need to multiply $\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$ to $m(x)$ in $c_2(x)$. And, I hope $m(x)$ is a 0/1 coefficient polynomial. I don't think it is a problem if the secret polynomial $s(x)$ has negative values. Also, $B(x) = s(x) \cdot A(x)$, right? And, what is your choice of $R$?

thank you for the clarification. yes m(x) is a 0/1 coefficient polynomial. B(x)=s(x)⋅A(x)+e(x) mod R. I choose R with small degree and coefficient for practice, R=Z149[x]/[x^12+1]

Let's continue the discussion in the following chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154024/lattice-rlwe-encryption-and-decryption-process
